# image next to link/text

Tags: html, css

I have a big problem with probably a very simple solution.

It's a news ticker and I use the construction below to add a single news/info ITEM, which consists of a short TEXT and a link (I want to be able to change text/link color or its background color and I'm not going to overuse such effects)):

```
<p>TEXT <a href="http:/www.example.com" style="background-color:#ffffff">
    <font color="4206FC">TEXT</font>
</a></p>
```

What should I do to insert a little 10x10px image "bluecircle.png" before text+link combo?

My newbie "coding skills" make one of them (either image or text+link DISAPPEAR/invisible).

UPDATE: I'm NOT a coder/programmer/developer. I'm a graphic designer, so THE SIMPLER/more basic the solution is the better for me.

UPDATE2: maybe this can (or can't) help, but every news/info item is inside this code:`<li id='item1'></li>`.

I want to honestly thank everyone here who wants to help me!:)
Don't know why nothing works like image+text+link:|

I see 4 different results:
1. nothing is visible (news item disappears altogether)
2. text+link is there, image is absent (i checked different paths, located image in 2 places, tried both)
3. image ICON is there, text+link combo is absent
4. my weird/outdated attempts to make it work: I do have IMAGE there and NO text+link.

Comment: Check out the css tags, :before, and :after.  Reading an article on that may contain the answer you are looking for.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HLQYD/

Comment: Also check out the CSS rules for colouring your text/links instead of using outdated `<font>` tags, maybe put the whole thing into a class along with your background colour

Comment: thank you a lot for your answers:) I'm not sure I can learn CSS/HTML fast/deep enough to make it work in the nearest future).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class to your code and paste the following in your stylesheet.

```
.circleimage:before{
content:url('bluecircle.png') 
position:relative;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
left:-10px;
top:10px;
}
```

Comment: Probably I've done something weird, but I used the code from the @imguru's answer below, replaced "newsLink" in it with "circleimage" from your answer and put your CSS code in ticker's CSS. Now the text+link combo works perfectly, but the image (I dropped it in root directory and "images" directory) doesn't.:|

Comment: Try changing the url to something like url('../images/bluecircle.png')

Comment: I've ALMOST found the problem, something is causing the construction image+text+link look like a vertical list: image is on top, text+link is under it and the HEIGHT of the ticker HIDES the bottom part...:|

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @andrew ice, what you need is pseudo classes (although there are lots of other ways to implement this)

```
<p id="newsLink">TEXT <a href="http:/www.example.com" style="background-color:#ffffff"><font color="4206FC">TEXT</font></a></p>
```

In your CSS, add the following:

```
#newsLink:before{
content:url('bluecircle.png');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've put the code above where news/info items are and the code below in ticker' CSS and now even the image doesn't work (broken image icon):(

Comment: The broken image icon comes up because the browser cannot find your image at the provided path. So if your html and image are in the same folder, url('bluecircle.png') would work. But if your image is within an 'img' folder, use url('img/bluecircle.png').. if you want to do trial n error, you can test out different URLs until you find the right one, using Chrome's developer (right click on the image and Inspect element).. Read up on relative paths if you wanna know more

Comment: I'm going to to try to change its paths right now again! thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you will understand this: since span is the inline element, you can use the img tag along with the span to make the all contents appear in single line.

```
<p>
 <span> Text </span>
 <span> <img src="path">   </span>
 <span>
   <a href="http:/www.example.com" style="background-color:#fff:>
   <font color="4206FC">TEXT</font>
   </a>
 </span>
<p>
```

Comment: I want to make it work desperately:| This code looks more like what I've tried on my own, but the only visible RESULT is "Text".